# Dynamic Pivot SQL with multiple aggregations

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I have a query that pulls through a dynamic list of columns (ie the columns can change at any time) and pivots the data showing he Maximum InstalledDate for those columns.  My question is however, how do I pull through more than one aggregation?  I need to have the Max LocationCode, MakeCode and ModelCode for each PlaceRef too but am struggling to do this.  Many thanks in advance.

```
    DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(Component ) 
  FROM (SELECT p.Component FROM VwLocationComponentCurrent AS p
    INNER JOIN VwLocationListEntriesCurrent AS o ON p.PlaceRef = o.PlaceRef
    where o.LocationList = N'NEWBUILD'
    GROUP BY p.Component) AS x;



SET @sql = N'
SELECT PlaceRef, Address1, StreetName, PostCode, Substatus, BuildingType, BuildDate, ' + STUFF(@columns , 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT 
  vwLocationCurrent.PlaceRef
  ,vwLocationCurrent.BuildDate
  ,vwLocationCurrent.SubStatus
  ,vwLocationCurrent.StreetName
  ,vwLocationCurrent.Address1
  ,vwLocationCurrent.Address2
  ,vwLocationCurrent.Address3
  ,vwLocationCurrent.PostCode
  ,VwLocationComponentCurrent.Component
  ,VwLocationComponentCurrent.SubLocationCode
  ,VwLocationComponentCurrent.InstalledDate
  ,VwLocationComponentCurrent.MakeCode
  ,VwLocationComponentCurrent.ModelCode
  ,VwLocationListEntriesCurrent.LocationList
  ,vwLocationCurrent.BuildingType

FROM
  vwLocationCurrent
  INNER JOIN VwLocationListEntriesCurrent
    ON vwLocationCurrent.PlaceRef = VwLocationListEntriesCurrent.PlaceRef
  LEFT OUTER JOIN VwLocationComponentCurrent
    ON vwLocationCurrent.PlaceRef = VwLocationComponentCurrent.PlaceRef
    WHERE
VwLocationListEntriesCurrent.LocationList = ''NEWBUILD''
) AS j

PIVOT
(
  MAX(InstalledDate) FOR Component IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;'
;
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: @Deb if someone asks you what the database is, add that database as a tag (which I just did). The tags are important.

Comment: OK Thanks, I had put SQL in the tag, just not SQL-Server, cheers.

Comment: for multiple aggregation, it is easier to use `MAX(CASE WHEN ... END)` approach

Comment: Not sure I can use MAX(CASE WHEN .. ) as the column names are dynamically created and there are over 50 of them at any time

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't use the "pivot" feature here, instead use an older technique employing "conditional aggregates". This means the creation of the "columns" string is more complex but it does allow you to output multiple aggregations in a single query. The following code is untested as there is no sample data to work with:

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max)
      , @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT
       @columns +=
     + N', max(case when Component = p.' + QUOTENAME(Component) + N' then SubLocationCode end) as ' + QUOTENAME('Loc_' + Component)
     + N', max(case when Component = p.' + QUOTENAME(Component) + N' then MakeCode end) as ' + QUOTENAME('Mak_' + Component)
     + N', max(case when Component = p.' + QUOTENAME(Component) + N' then ModelCode end) as '+  QUOTENAME('Mod_' + Component)
FROM (
    SELECT
        p.Component
    FROM VwLocationComponentCurrent AS p
    INNER JOIN VwLocationListEntriesCurrent AS o ON p.PlaceRef = o.PlaceRef
    WHERE o.LocationList = N'NEWBUILD'
    GROUP BY
        p.Component
) AS x;

SET @sql = N'
SELECT PlaceRef, Address1, StreetName, PostCode, SubStatus, BuildingType, BuildDate, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   vwLocationCurrent.PlaceRef
  ,vwLocationCurrent.Address1
  ,vwLocationCurrent.StreetName
  ,vwLocationCurrent.PostCode
  ,vwLocationCurrent.SubStatus
  ,vwLocationCurrent.BuildingType
  ,vwLocationCurrent.BuildDate'
+ STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
+ N' FROM vwLocationCurrent
  INNER JOIN VwLocationListEntriesCurrent
    ON vwLocationCurrent.PlaceRef = VwLocationListEntriesCurrent.PlaceRef
  LEFT OUTER JOIN VwLocationComponentCurrent
    ON vwLocationCurrent.PlaceRef = VwLocationComponentCurrent.PlaceRef
  WHERE VwLocationListEntriesCurrent.LocationList = ''NEWBUILD''
  GROUP BY
   vwLocationCurrent.PlaceRef
  ,vwLocationCurrent.Address1
  ,vwLocationCurrent.StreetName
  ,vwLocationCurrent.PostCode
  ,vwLocationCurrent.SubStatus
  ,vwLocationCurrent.BuildingType
) AS p;'
;
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks, just trying to understand it but as I try to run it gives me the following error:  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '('.